# Data Mining Books

Tags: books, artificial-intelligence, data-mining

I'm passionate about *data mining*, I have read some books like *Programming Collective Intelligence*, and I would like to know more good **books**, specially practical ones, **about *data mining*** in conjunction with *AI*. Any tips will be appreciated as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok. The following books are the top books that any data mining lover would recommend you reading:

1. [Artificial Intelligence: A Modern Approach](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0136042597)
2. [Data Mining: Practical Machine Learning Tools and Techniques, Third Edition](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0123748569)
3. [Data Mining: Concepts and Techniques, Second Edition](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1558609016)

Read those and you "won't need" any more theory =) However, you will need to get your hands dirty.

Answer (score 4):

[Data Mining, 3rd Edition](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0120884070) is really extensive and useful book. I read it to learn about Data Mining. It contains advanced Data Mining subjects like "Real Machine Learning Schemes", "Data Transformation", "Ensemble Learning" and Weka data mining project.

[Machine Learning and Data Mining for Computer Security](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/184628029X) as it is obvious discuses data mining in the perspective of Computers security.

[Data Mining Concepts, Models and Techniques](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3642197205) is a gentle introduction and a well explained book about data mining in general.

Answer (score 2):

A brilliant introduction to the concepts of data mining and statistical analysis can be found in Gordon Linoff's [Data Analysis Using SQL and Excel](http://books.google.be/books/about/Data_analysis_using_SQL_and_Excel.html?id=_NaqvTLuthsC&redir_esc=y) book.

This is a great book if your background is in data warehousing, data analysis or business intelligence

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you have built the requisite mathematical foundation. In any case, here's a good, comprehensive guide from the basics to the advanced -

http://measuringmeasures.blogspot.com/2010/01/learning-about-statistical-learning.html

Edit: From your profile I see that you just started CS in college, hence I would suggest that you build the base first and then move on to actual data mining.

Comment: Link is no longer  valid

Comment: Looks like the entire blog has been removed. Here it is on the Wayback Machine - http://web.archive.org/web/20100118082135/http://measuringmeasures.blogspot.com/2010/01/learning-about-statistical-learning.html

Answer (score 1):

I've looked at several of the suggested books and have found [Introduction to Machine Learning by Pan, Steinbach and Kumar](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321321367) to be the best. One thing it has that most of the others don't is a whole chapter at the beginning on data preparation and how to represent data to the algorithms. I've not found a better treatment of that very important piece of data mining.